# Нужна помощь в построении запроса в Eloquent ORM Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть таблица постов `posts (id, name)`, есть таблица `тэгов tags (id, name)`.
Связаны они между собой с помощью связи *"многие ко многим"*, через вспомогательную таблицу `post_tag (id_post и id_tag)`.

Необходимо, зная `id` *тэга*, выбрать все связные `посты`.

Как правильно реализовать такую выборку помощью конструктора запросов `laravel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Закиньте в модель Tag связь

```
public function posts() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_tag ', 'id_post', 'id');
}
```

А в модель Post связь

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tag', 'id_tag', 'id');
}
```

Запросы для проверки:

```
$tags = Tag::with('posts')->get();
$posts = Post::with('tags')->get();
dump($tags);
dump($posts);
die;
```

Answer (score 2):

Наверное как то так я думаю. Через join:

```
DB::select('select * from tags as t
            join post_tag as pt ON pt.id_tag = t.id
            join posts as p ON p.id = pt.id_post 
             where pt.id_tag= ?', [$id]);
```

Тут выборка идёт по tags и к ней join'нятся  другие таблицы.